# Escape Html Text in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a text like this:

```
<p><strong>Lorem</strong> ipsur&nbsp;</p>
```

To see a text without html tags in Zend Framework 2 how can I do?

I tried to put:

```
<?php echo $this->escapehtml($array['text']); ?>
```

I read that for security is not good to do:

```
<?php echo $array['descrizione']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if i understand the question, since i dont know the contents of your arrays.

basicaly if you want to scape the contents of a variable, let's say, `$input`, you have to call, as you mentioned

```
$this>escapeHtml($input)
```

Actually, the  PhpRenderer includes a selection of helpers you can use for this purpose: EscapeHtml, EscapeHtmlAttr, EscapeJs, EscapeCss, and EscapeUrl.

You can read about this [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.php-renderer.scripts.html)

Also, if you want more control, you can use Zend\Escaper, that in 2 lines of code allow you to [escape html](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.escaper.escaping-html.html), like this

```
$escaper = new Zend\Escaper\Escaper('utf-8');
$output = $escaper->escapeHtml($input);
```

or [escape attributes](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.escaper.escaping-html-attributes.html), like this

```
$escaper = new Zend\Escaper\Escaper('utf-8');
$output = $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($input);
```

I recommend you read the 3 links, they are very short and would give you a better undestanding of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment there is no option in escapeHtml to allow certain tags. What you have to do in these specific cases is to modify the returned value:

```
<?php
$str = $this->escapehtml($array['text']); ?>
$str = preg_replace(
    array('#href=&quot;(.*)&quot;#', '#&lt;(/?(?:pre|a|b|br|em|u|ul|li|ol|p|strong)(\shref=".*")?/?)&gt;#' ), 
    array( 'href="\1"', '<\1>' ), 
    $str
);
echo $str;
```

You can add/remove tags from the part `pre|a|b|br|em|u|ul|li|ol|p|strong` to your needs. Also this code will allow anchor tags with href only.